# Unable to setup Jenkins war with java command

Tags: java, jenkins

I am trying to setup Jenkins on first step I got following error
when running the command "java -jar jenkins.war"

```
SEVERE: Running with Java class version 55.0, but 52.0 is required.Run with the --enable-future-java flag to enable such behavior. See https://jenkins.io/redirect/java-support/
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 55.0
    at Main.main(Main.java:139)

Jenkins requires Java 8, but you are running 11.0.1+13-LTS from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 55.0
    at Main.main(Main.java:139)
```

Can any one guild me how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

I think the errormessage is quite clear. **You are trying to run Jenkins with Java version 11, while it would prefer Java 8.**

According to the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/) Java 11 is not fully supported yet, but as the errormessage suggest, you can make it work by using the `--enable-future-java` flag via command line.

**The more safe option is to install and use the Java version preferred by the Jenkins team**, which is Java 8 at this point. For that you need to install of course that version on your machine first.

Answer (score 3):

It works with "java -jar jenkins.war --enable-future-java --httpPort=9090".

Steps:

1. Go to directory where Jenkins.war is places
2. open cmd
3. Enter java -jar jenkins.war --enable-future-java --httpPort=9090

Jenkins will start. then Go to "http://localhost:9090/" and enter "initialAdminPassword" then Jenkins will start properly.

Comment: Is it possible to set `--enable-future-java` permanently? I've tried putting `JENKINS_ARGS="--enable-future-java"` in my `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download JDK 11 version as ZIp version
2. Open Command Prompt or terminal
3. set PATH=<Path of JDK 11 or JDK8 Bin folder>;%PATH% (For windows)
4. Check for Java -version, it shows JDK 11 or 8
5. Run java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=

Answer (score 0):

If you have more Recent Java version installed, Run

```
java -jar jenkins.war --enable-future-java --httpPort=xxxx
```